Fitting column width and entire table in tex in overleaf
I am trying to insert a huge table in my tex document. I have 9 columns and 22 rows. I used multiple tricks but the last columns of my table does not seem to properly fit in the tex document. I am using overleaf. I tried using \usepackage{tabularx} and \centering to fit the table but then the column width became too small and the text didn't fit properly in the cell.

Here is my code.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
%\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
\hline
Characteristics       & Benin & Cameroon & Cote d’Ivoire & Ghana & Kenya & Liberia & Nigeria & Uganda \\
\hline
Adequacy components     &       &          &               &       &       &         &         &        \\
\hline
Bean, peas, lentils, nuts   & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$  & $\uparrow$   & $\uparrow$    & $\downarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\uparrow$      \\
\hline
Bread / noodles   & $\leftrightarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$        & $\leftrightarrow$  & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\uparrow$      \\
\hline
Mangoes, papayas, and other Vit A fruits & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$  & $\downarrow$             & $\leftrightarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Other fruits  & $\uparrow$     & $\uparrow$  & $\downarrow$   & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Juice   & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$        & $\downarrow$  & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & ↓      \\
\hline
Soup/clear broth   & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$        & $\downarrow$    & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\downarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Optimum components     &       &          &               &       &       &         &         &        \\
\hline
Eggs     & $\downarrow$     & $\downarrow$        & $\downarrow$             & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Fish or shellfish & $\uparrow$     & $\downarrow$        & $\downarrow$             & $\downarrow$     & $\downarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Powdered or fresh milk   & $\downarrow$     & $\downarrow$        & $\downarrow$             & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\downarrow$      & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Cheese, yogurt or other milk products    & $\downarrow$     & $\downarrow$        & $\downarrow$  & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\downarrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Yogurt   & $\uparrow$     & $\downarrow$        & $\downarrow$   & $\uparrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\leftrightarrow$     \\
\hline
Potatoes, Cassava and other tubers       & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$        & $\downarrow$    & $\leftrightarrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$      & $\uparrow$       & $\leftrightarrow$     \\
\hline
Ratio components   &       &          &               &       &       &         &         &        \\
\hline
Pumpkin, carrots, squash   & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$        & $\downarrow$             & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\leftrightarrow$      \\
\hline
Dark green leafy vegetables   & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$        & $\downarrow$             & $\uparrow$     & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\uparrow$      \\
\hline
Moderation components                    &       &          &               &       &       &         &         &        \\
\hline
Baby formula   & $\downarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$        & $\downarrow$  & $\downarrow$     & $\downarrow$     & $\uparrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Fortified baby food   & $\uparrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$        & NA            & NA    & NA    & $\uparrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Meat (beef, pork, lamb, chicken, etc)    & $\downarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$        & ↓             & ↓     & $\uparrow$     & $\uparrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\downarrow$      \\
\hline
Liver, heart, other organs   & $\downarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$        & $\leftrightarrow$  & $\downarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$     & $\leftrightarrow$       & $\uparrow$       & $\leftrightarrow$  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
%\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I apologize for bad question.I am new and just starting to learn overleaf. I will modify my question. I agree it is important to prepare a good question.

I've taken the liberty of deleting the "original code" portion of your answer, as I think readers will only care about the augmented/compilable version of your code. Feel free to revert.

I've taken the liberty of (a) deleting the "original code" portion of your answer, as I think readers will only care about the augmented/compilable version of your code and (b) posting a screenshot.

Every country is assigned codes and they're universally accepted. Just add a legend at the bottom of the table so people not acquainted with them can find the correspondence.
Avoid caged tables (that is, those with vertical rules and too many horizontal ones).
I defined a few local commands to ease input and readability of the code.
The array package is needed (it's loaded by tabularx if you really need it). Do you really need all those packages? I don't think that investigations over food requires algorithmic and friends or listings.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{textcomp}% no longer needed
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx} % either this one or algpseudocode, not both
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX compute
\newcommand{\ua}{$\uparrow$}
\newcommand{\da}{$\downarrow$}
\newcommand{\lra}{$\leftrightarrow$}


\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
 @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
 l *{8}{c}
}
\toprule
Characteristics & 
BEN & CMR & CIV & GHA & KEN & LBR & NGA & UGA \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\itshape Adequacy components} \\
Bean, peas, lentils, nuts & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \ua  & \da  & \lra & \ua  & \ua  \\
Bread/noodles             & \lra & \lra & \lra & \da  & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \ua  \\
Mangoes, papayas, and 
other Vit A fruits        & \da  & \ua  & \da  & \lra & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \da  \\
Other fruits              & \ua  & \ua  & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \da  \\
Juice                     & \ua  & \lra & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \da  \\
Soup/clear broth          & \da  & \ua  & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \da  & \ua  & \da  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\itshape Optimum components} \\
Eggs                      & \da  & \da  & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \da  \\
Fish or shellfish         & \ua  & \da  & \da  & \da  & \da  & \lra & \ua  & \da  \\
Powdered or fresh milk    & \da  & \da  & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \da  & \ua  & \da  \\
Cheese, yogurt or other 
milk products             & \da  & \da  & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \lra & \da  & \da  \\
Yogurt                    & \ua  & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \lra \\
Potatoes, Cassava and 
other tubers              & \da  & \ua  & \da  & \lra & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \lra \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\itshape Ratio components} \\
Pumpkin, carrots, squash  & \da  & \ua  & \da  & \ua  & \lra & \lra & \lra & \lra \\
Dark green leafy 
vegetables                & \da  & \ua  & \da  & \ua  & \ua  & \lra & \ua  & \ua  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\itshape Moderation components} \\
Baby formula              & \da  & \lra & \da  & \da  & \da  & \ua  & \ua  & \da  \\
Fortified baby food       & \ua  & \lra & NA   & NA   & NA   & \ua  & \ua  & \da  \\
Meat (beef, pork, 
lamb, chicken, etc)       & \da  & \lra & \da  & \da   & \ua  & \ua  & \ua  & \da  \\
Liver, heart, 
other organs              & \da  & \lra & \lra & \da  & \lra & \lra & \ua  & \lra \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{4}{l}}
BEN: Benin & CMR: Cameroon & CIV: Cote d’Ivoire & GHA: Ghana  \\
KEN: Kenya & LBR: Liberia  & NGA: Nigeria       & UGA: Uganda \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}



I would reverse the logic of the tabularx setup: Instead of setting up 1 l-type column (which doesn't allow line breaking) and 8 X-type columns, I suggest you create 1 X-type column (on the left, to allow for automatic line breaking) and 8 fixed-width columns that also permit automatic line breaking. By setting the fixed width of the 8 data columns to that of the word "Uganda", only two header cells -- those for "Cameroon" and "Cote d'Ivoire" -- will need to be line-broken by LaTeX.
I would also arrange for more visual prominence of the four "component cells": Adequacy Components, Optimum Components, Ratio Components, and Moderation Components.

\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp} % are you sure you need this package
\usepackage{manyfoot} % ditto
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro
%%\usepackage{booktabs} % don't load packages more than once
\usepackage{tabularx}

%% new
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{cam-er-oon} % that's the hyphenation pattern according to Merriam Webster
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macros
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}m{\widthof{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}    % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped "look"

%% don't forget to provide a '\caption' directive

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|*{8}{C{Uganda}|}} 
\hline
Characteristics & Benin & Cameroon & Cote d'Ivoire & Ghana & Kenya & Liberia & Nigeria & Uganda \\
\hline
\textsc{Adequacy Components} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{} \\
\hline
Bean, peas, lentils, nuts & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ \\
\hline
Bread\slash noodles & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ \\
\hline
Mangoes, papayas, and other Vit A fruits & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Other fruits & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Juice & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & ↓ \\
\hline
Soup\slash clear broth & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
\textsc{Optimum Components} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{} \\
\hline
Eggs & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Fish or shellfish & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Powdered or fresh milk & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Cheese, yogurt or other milk products & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Yogurt & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\
\hline
Potatoes, Cassava and other tubers & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\
\hline
\textsc{Ratio Components} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{} \\
\hline
Pumpkin, carrots, squash & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\
\hline
Dark green leafy vegetables & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ \\
\hline
\textsc{Moderation Components} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{} \\
\hline
Baby formula & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Fortified baby food & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & \textsc{na} & \textsc{na} & \textsc{na} & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Meat (beef, pork, lamb, chicken, etc) & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & ↓ & ↓ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
\hline
Liver, heart, other organs & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Addendum: Since your document loads the booktabs package, why not put it to good use by getting rid of all vertical rules and using far fewer, but well spaced, horizontal rules? This change will result in a much more open and inviting look. This visual invitatioin just may do the trick of enticing your readers to actually linger on the table and make an effort to absorb its information.

\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,calc,tabularx}

%% new
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{cam-er-oon} % that's the hyphenation pattern according to Merriam Webster
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}m{\widthof{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % default: 6pt

% don't forget to provide a caption...

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{8}{C{Uganda}} @{}}

\toprule
Characteristics & Benin & Cameroon & Cote d'Ivoire & Ghana & Kenya & Liberia & Nigeria & Uganda \\
\midrule

\textsc{Adequacy Components}  \\

Bean, peas, lentils, nuts & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ \\ 
Bread\slash noodles & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ \\
Mangoes, papayas, and other Vitamin~A fruits & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
Other fruits & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
Juice & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & ↓ \\
Soup\slash clear broth & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\

\addlinespace
\textsc{Optimum Components}  \\

Eggs & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\  
Fish or shellfish & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\  
Powdered or fresh milk & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
Cheese, yogurt or other milk products & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
Yogurt & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\
Potatoes, Cassava and other tubers & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\

\addlinespace
\textsc{Ratio Components}  \\

Pumpkin, carrots, squash & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\
Dark green leafy vegetables & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ \\

\addlinespace
\textsc{Moderation Components}  \\

Baby formula & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
Fortified baby food & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & \textsc{na} & \textsc{na} & \textsc{na} & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
Meat (beef, pork, lamb, chicken, etc) & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & ↓ & ↓ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\downarrow$ \\
Liver, heart, other organs & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\downarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ & $\uparrow$ & $\leftrightarrow$ \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}

